# How to randomly select 3 elements and remove them from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I need help with a function to select 3 random elements within an array, and to remove them from the array.

Comment: You might start by generating random numbers that are integers in the range 0 to array.length, then *splice* them from the array. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove one random element from the array with `Math.random` and `splice`, and do this three times:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple pure js approache...
You could use ecma filter to do so too but i went for the basic.

Tough running same line 3 times makes me feel like something inside me dies a bit.....

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function removeRandomly(array, numberOfDeletions) {
    for(var i=0;i<numberOfDeletions;i++){
        array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1)
    }
    console.log(array)
}

removeRandomly(array, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a recursive function which takes an array and deletes count. Plus, I prefer using filter instead of the splice in a different way.

```js
function removeRandom(array, number) {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  const result = array.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== array[randomIndex]
  });
  if (number > 1)
    return removeRandom(result, number - 1)
  else
    return result
}
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const result = removeRandom(a, 3)
console.log(result)
```